# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & (When i stored value after serializing object) this error comes on View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I try to alert value come from Db. I stored this value by serializing it into Javascript.
But when i try to alert this value on View it through error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & "
Here is the column value placed in DB

```
["TotalCriteria:Total Criteria","{CriteriaID:1,Title:abc,Required:Not Required}","{CriteriaID:2,Title:abc55,Required:Not Required}","{CriteriaID:3,Title:adas,Required:Rquired}","{CriteriaID:5,Title:New,Required:Not Required}","MeetCriteria:Meet","{CriteriaID:1,Title:abc}","{CriteriaID:2,Title:abc55}","{CriteriaID:3,Title:adas}","{CriteriaID:5,Title:New}"]
```

I try to parse it Using JSON object in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var msg = JSON.parse(@Model.QualifyDetail);
alert(msg);
});
```

**Edit (BackendCode)**

```
CModel.QualifyDetail = JsonString(entities);
    public string JsonString(Entity[] entities)
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        list.Add("TotalCriteria:Total Criteria");
        string requiredStatus = null;
        int CROID = new VM_CROEmployee().FindById(VM_User2.LoggedInUserID()).CROID;
        List<VM_QualifyCriteria> Criteria = new VM_QualifyCriteria().FindAllByAttributes(c => c.CROID == CROID);

        foreach(VM_QualifyCriteria obj in Criteria)
        {
            if (obj.IsRequired == true)
                requiredStatus = "Rquired";
            else
                requiredStatus = "Not Required";
            list.Add("{CriteriaID:" + obj.CriteriaID + ",Title:" + obj.Title + ",Required:" + requiredStatus + "}");
        }
        list.Add("MeetCriteria:Meet");
        foreach(Entity obj in entities)
        {
            if (obj.State == true)
            {
                list.Add("{CriteriaID:" + new VM_QualifyCriteria().FindById(obj.CriteriaId).CriteriaID +",Title:"+new VM_QualifyCriteria().FindById(obj.CriteriaId).Title+"}");
            }
        }
        //string qualifyDescription=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list);
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list); 
    }
```

Comment: Could you show me, rendered script with actual value instead of model.qualifydetail

Comment: Actual Values are added in Question. if i rendered this value using Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.QualifyDetail);
It rendered well as i wanted.

Comment: When i try this
$(document).ready(function () {
var test = '@Html.Raw(Model.QualifyDetail)';
      
        var msg = $.parseJSON(test);
        var arr = new Array();
        arr =msg[1];

        alert(arr.CriteriaID);
    });
It shows the actual result but now the problem is that when i access its [1] index it gives me whole array but i wanted its subindexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to parse the JSON, just output the JSON into the script. `msg` will already be a JavaScript array so there's no need to parse it again.

(Use [`HtmlHelper.Raw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or else the quotes will be HTML encoded)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var msg = @Html.Raw(Model.QualifyDetail);
    alert(msg[0]);
});
```

This will output (JSON formatted for readability):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var msg = [
        "TotalCriteria:Total Criteria",
        "{CriteriaID:1,Title:abc,Required:Not Required}",
        "{CriteriaID:2,Title:abc55,Required:Not Required}",
        "{CriteriaID:3,Title:adas,Required:Rquired}",
        "{CriteriaID:5,Title:New,Required:Not Required}",
        "MeetCriteria:Meet",
        "{CriteriaID:1,Title:abc}",
        "{CriteriaID:2,Title:abc55}",
        "{CriteriaID:3,Title:adas}",
        "{CriteriaID:5,Title:New}"
    ];
    alert(msg[0]);  // should alert "TotalCriteria:Total Criteria"
});
```

As mentioned by others, while this *is* valid JSON (it's an array of strings), it appears to represent a more complex data structure but it was mangled during serialization. You'll probably need to fix that before you can use it.

**Edit**

A better way of representing the data might be an object with 2 arrays, one with all criteria, and one with criteria that have been met. Something like this:

```
{
    "TotalCriteria": [
        {
            "CriteriaID": 1,
            "Title": "abc",
            "Required": "Not Required"
        },
        {
            "CriteriaID": 2,
            "Title": "abc55",
            "Required": "Not Required"
        },
        {
            "CriteriaID": 3,
            "Title": "adas",
            "Required": "Required"
        },
        {
            "CriteriaID": 5,
            "Title": "New",
            "Required": "Not Required"
        }
    ],
    "MeetCriteria": [
        {
            "CriteriaID": 1,
            "Title": "abc"
        },
        {
            "CriteriaID": 2,
            "Title": "abc55"
        },
        {
            "CriteriaID": 3,
            "Title": "adas"
        },
        {
            "CriteriaID": 5,
            "Title": "New"
        }
    ]
}
```

To access a criteria, you would do this...

```
var msg0 = msg.TotalCriteria[0];
alert(msg0.CriteriaID);
alert(msg0.Title);
alert(msg0.Required);
```

Here's how you can construct the above JSON in your backend code using LINQ to create an object containing two lists of objects, then serializing it...

```
public string JsonString(Entity[] entities)
{
    int CROID = new VM_CROEmployee().FindById(VM_User2.LoggedInUserID()).CROID;
    List<VM_QualifyCriteria> criteria = new VM_QualifyCriteria().FindAllByAttributes(c => c.CROID == CROID);

    // get a list of all criteria
    var totalCriteria = criteria.Select(c => new {
        c.CriteriaID,
        c.Title,
        Required = c.IsRequired ? "Required" : "Not Required"
    }).ToList();

    // get list of criteria met
    var meetCriteria = criteria
                        .Where(c => entities.Any(e => e.State == true && e.CriteriaId == c.CriteriaID))
                        .Select(c => new {
                            c.CriteriaID,
                            c.Title
                        }).ToList();

    // construct object with the 2 lists
    var obj = new { TotalCriteria = totalCriteria, MeetCriteria = meetCriteria };

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj); 
}
```

Comment: Yeah @Anthony you are right (y) when i try this it works fine can you please tell me how i access array when i try msg[1] it gives me "{CriteriaID:1,Title:abc,Required:Not Required}" Is it possible to access CriteriaID in this particular array similarly Title and Required also needed.

Comment: Updated answer with how you could use `JSON.parse()` to turn it into an object.

Comment: It looks like that's not going to work. None of the strings in the array are valid JSON. You have to fix the way these things are serialized when saved to the database.

Comment: I tried it the same way as you suggest.
var msg1 = JSON.parse(msg[1]);
alert(msg1.CriteriaId);
But not alert any thing. Uncaught SyntaxError. Enexpected end of input

Comment: i share the code i used for Serialization then you may correct me easily.

Comment: Please update the question with the code, not the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please check Question now.

Comment: Added some suggestions... I made some assumptions and typed the answer without a compiler so forgive me if there are some mistakes in there. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @Anthony .. Please fix my another issue generated
When i try this
var msg0 = msg.TotalCriteria[0];
alert(msg0.CriteriaID);
alert(msg0.Title);
alert(msg0.Required);
The error occurred
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Thanks @Anthony for detailed help i get rid off from this problem Actually i read data by using single colon like that
var msg='@Html.Raw(Model.QualifyDetail)';
when removed these single Colon it works fine and get the required values as needed ..
If here is button for unlimited appreciation i will press it for you. :p

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a jsonarray that in-turn has string and jsonObject as its elements
so first see whether you have the JsonArray response from server by alerting it 
then select each element in array like

```
var jsonArray=response;
alert(jsonArray);//check the response
alert(jsonArray[0]); //first element
```

then treat the jsonObject element like wise to access it

To check your json response is valid use http://jsonlint.com/